# Make recoll index sqlite files

Tags: sqlite, recoll

How do I make recoll index sqlite files?

By default, it doesn't appear to do this.

My backup plan is to regularly `sqlite3 x .dump > x.dump` for each db 
x (and let recoll index x.dump), but I'm hoping there's a more direct 
way.

Answer (score 2):

Recoll can't index a SQLite database directly at the moment. It should be possible to write a filter to do it, but it would probably need to be specific to the database schema to really make sense.